# Hiding secrets in puppet agent logs?

Tags: security, passwords, puppet

Related to: [Handling sensitive information with Puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171472/handling-sensitive-information-with-puppet)

Just noticed that with both augeas and templates our passwords get dumped into /var/log/messages in plain text whenever there is a change.

What methods can be used to prevent this?

Comment: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2722

Answer (score 2):

I added filters to rsyslog's config to drop sensitive log info.

Seems to work. Takes a bit to get the filters dropping what you want and not what you don't want.

Comment: Probably the only way at this point but i'm not quite ready to mark this as the answer. :/

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed in the ask.puppet post [Passwords in Puppet Log files](https://ask.puppet.com/question/13989/passwords-in-puppet-log-files/). The post includes several options, including validating the rsyslog scrubbing method.

The main method that prevents the passwords from being displayed in your logs without extra filtering or without losing other logs is to pass `show_diff => false` to the appropriate resources such as [file](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/file.html#file-attribute-show_diff), [augeas](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/augeas.html#augeas-attribute-show_diff), and [concat](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat#show_diff).